# Use of Parameter in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting, query-string

I have to fetch data from table MonthWise. I have created a PARAMETER - @SELECTMONTH and kept this parameter as static. I had put specific value in available values i.e.

for eg. Label - Jan Value - Jan

```
       Label - Feb Value - Feb and so on
```

I have used this parameter in query. i.e.

Select Month FROM Table WHERE Month in (@SelectMonth)

Union all

Select 'Jan-Feb' as Month FROM Table Where Month in ('Jan-19','Feb-19')

Union all

Select 'Jan-Feb-Mar' as Month FROM Table Where Month in ('Jan-19','Feb-19','Mar-19')

Under DataSet Properties > Parameters > Add > Parameter Name - @SelectMonth and Parameter Value - [@SelectMonth] - under this expression is =Parameters!SelectMonth.Value

All this are the factors in report. and when report runs I am able to see SelectMonth Parameter and able to select multiple months and data is been displayed accordingly I select the months.

But this is 50 % of requirement only done. Another requirement is I have to display months at the end of the report, which is written in UNION ALL query. I am able to display it by use of UNION ALL query. But the requirement is to display as per the month selected in parameter checkbox.

For eg. If I select Jan-Feb-Mar, than it should display as

Jan

Feb

Mar

Jan-Feb

Jan-Feb-Mar

But if I deselect for eg. Mar, than it should remove Mar from the Month which is at the end of report. Here I am able to remove from single month, as required month Mar is not showing/data is not been fetched in single month field but it is till fetching month Mar in end where it is joining months Jan-Feb-Mar.  I do not even want that month Mar to be joined at end either. it should be removed totally from everywhere. it is should look like as below: but I am not able to do it.

Jan

Feb

Jan-Feb

If anyone can help that how should I put it ? I was wondering to use IF condition, that IF @SelectMonth = 'Jan' then only that much data should be displayed in single month column and even to the join month column.

But i am not able to figure out exactly. so please if anyone can help that will be great.

Thank you so much everyone in advance.

Comment: Have you considered doing multi select parameter with a single query without all the unions? What you are describing seems rather convoluted!  Plus - screen shots of desired results speaks volumes over words trying to describe your issue!

Comment: @Harry thank you for your reply. I have used to select allow multiple values under Report Parameter Properties of SelectMonth Parameter. Other things I am trying  but not working as desired

Comment: @Harry thank you for your reply. I have used to select allow multiple values under Report Parameter Properties of SelectMonth Parameter. Other things I am trying  but not working as desired...

Comment: If you show what you mean.. it would be helpful.. by saying not working as desired leaves out a lot of detail!

Comment: @Harry I tried the upper code, now I don't know how to put query or condition and where to put it the condition ? so that I can get the result which is already I stated in my question I am not able to paste the images or else would have explained you better way.  Please refer my question. I am new to SSRS tool so do not know much of it how to work on it. Thank you